# Writing an .xsd for elements with attributes

Tags: attributes, xsd, element

I'm currently familiarising myself with xsd and xml just for fun, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to write an xsd for a simple (well, not really, since it has attributes) table with rows and columns and use XML mapping in Excel to display the data nicely. Rows for rows, and columns for columns like in tables one will usually see. e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<table name='Data1'>
<row>
<col name='id'>1</col>
<col name='x'>0</col>
<col name='y'>6</col>
<col name='z'>7</col></row>
<row>
<col name='id'>2</col>
<col name='x'>0</col>
<col name='y'>5</col>
<col name='z'>8</col></row>
<row>
<col name='id'>3</col>
<col name='x'>0</col>
<col name='y'>5</col>
<col name='z'>9</col></row></table>
```

In effect, it should look something like:

- id | x | y | z
- 1  | 0 | 6 | 7
- 2  | 0 | 5 | 8
- 3  | 0 | 5 | 9

Edited schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="table">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="col" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Did I add some extra ingredient or am missing something? I'm not really clear about this xsd thing yet. XD

Thanks in advance for anyone who could point out my mistake(s).

Comment: Do you at least have an error message or something more descriptive other than "it fails" ??

Comment: It is in Excel, stating that the xml file cannot be mapped. Status: Failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An xml is not validated by the scheme -- column element declaration is not complete.
Try this one:

```
<xs:element name='table'>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='row'>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name='col' minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string">
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name='name' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: What does one mean by 'An xml is not validated by the scheme?"
If the rows also have a number of instances, do I have to add minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"?

Comment: I mean that in your scheme row element has to contain "name" attribute, but in xml it is not presented. Also you define column as string element -- not custom complex element with your attributes. In "row" element add minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" attributes to allow element occur more than once.

Comment: I've edited my example for a more comprehensive look. I tried using the schema you showed me, but it still did not resolve the failure. I added the map, and when I import an xml example (as shown at the top), it still failed to map the xml. Is there still something I have to add in the xml, or is there something else I don't get? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Excel error: No elements mapped. and No data was imported or only some of the data was imported.

Comment: Better examine XSLT if you use XML mapping in Excel to display the data nicely just for fun. According XML mappings itself remove "name" attribute from column element and add separately element with concreete name in XSD schema instead one repeating element with name "col".

Comment: Does that explain why if I just let Excel automatically create a schema, it comes off with col and name having separate columns? =_=